# Are there "starts with" aliases in ZSH?

Tags: bash, alias, zsh, oh-my-zsh, startswith

I defined several aliases for folder that I often use; e.g.

```
alias x="cd /home/username/git/github/user/project"
```

So typing `x` in the terminal directly takes me to the project folder.

I thought it would be nice to define an alias that is also use, if a string only starts with the alias; e.g. if I defined

```
starts-with-alias x="cd /home/username/git/github/user/project"
```

typing

```
x/abc
```

would take me to:

```
/home/username/git/github/user/project/abc
```

Comment: You might want to consider `setopt autocd` and `cdpath+=(/home/username/git/github/user)`, which should allow `project` by itself to switch to the directory of the same name in your `.../github/user` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Using standard shell functions, you could do something like

```
x() { cd /home/username/git/github/user/project/"$1"; }
```

`x` would take you there, and `x abc` takes you to `/home/username/git/github/user/project/abc`.

Not exactly what you asked for, but very close.

Disclaimer: Only tested under `bash`; the standard syntax may vary, the `zsh`one as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [*Static Named Directories*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Static-named-directories) instead of aliases, possibly in conjunction with the options [`AUTO_CD` and/or `CDABLE_VARS`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Changing-Directories).

*Static named directories* are indicated by an `~` followed the name (which my contain any alphanumeric character, `_`, `-` or `.`). Typically they are used for the home directories of the users on a system, meaning `~someuser` will be replaced by the actual home directory of the user `someuser`.

In `zsh` you can also define your own *static named directories* with either of the following two methods:

- define a shell parameter with a value that starts with `/`:

  ```
  x=/home/username/git/github/user/project
  ```
- or use the `hash` command with parameter `-d` (works similar to alias):

  ```
  hash -d x=/home/username/git/github/user/project
  ```

The only difference between those two methods is, that the first one (obviously) provides a shell parameter, which you could possibly use in cases where named directories are not expanded (e.g. inside quoted strings) or export as environment variable.
With either method you can now access the directory `/home/username/git/github/user/project` with the name `~x`:

```
% cd ~x
% pwd
/home/username/git/github/user/project
```

It also works as the first component of a path:

```
% cd ~x/abc
% pwd
/home/username/git/github/user/project/abc
```

And as an added benefit compared to aliases it also works with other commands than just `cd`:

```
% touch ~x/somefile
% echo foobar > ~x/somefile
% cat ~x/somefile
foobar
```

---

With option `AUTO_CD` enabled, `zsh` will automatically change into a directory if it is issued in place of a command:

```
% setopt autocd
% ~x
% pwd
/home/username/git/github/user/project
% ~x/abc
% pwd
/home/username/git/github/user/project/abc
```

---

With the option `CDABLE_VARS` enabled, if the argument to a `cd` command (or an implied `cd` with `AUTO_CD` enabled) is not a directory and does not start with `/`, `zsh` will try to expand the argument as if it started with an `~`:

```
% setopt cdablevars
% cd x
% pwd
/home/username/git/github/user/project
% cd x/abc
% pwd
/home/username/git/github/user/project/abc
```

---

With both, `AUTO_CD` and `CDABLE_VARS`, enabled you can use *named directories* just like aliases for `cd` with the added benefits that you can directly access subdirectories.

```
% setopt autocd cdablevars
% x
% pwd
/home/username/git/github/user/project
% x/abc
% pwd
/home/username/git/github/user/project/abc
```

**Note:** When not using the named directory in the context of `cd` (either explicit or implicit via `AUTO_CD`) the name needs to be preceded by `~` in order to be expanded:

```
% echo x/abc
x/abc
% echo ~x/abc
/home/username/git/github/user/project/abc
```